# AVAudioPlayer doesn't play sound?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have a AVAudioPlayer in a seperate class, which I load into a ViewController. Here's the code:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class SoundController {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    init() {
    }

    func playAudio() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ring-ring", ofType: "aiff", inDirectory: "Media" )!
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            print("Let's play the sound")
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            self.audioPlayer = sound
            sound.play()
        } catch {
            print("Error playing sound file")
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sound = SoundController()
        sound.playAudio()
    }
```

Everything compiles and I get the console output "Let's play the sound", but no matter which device I test on, the sound doesn't play. Any advice what's wrong?

Comment: which object does keep your `sound` instance alive? no such thing in your code here, therefore the `sound` will be released immediately after `–viewDidLoad` runs out of the scope before even you can hear a thing.

Comment: maybe, understanding how ARC works.... that could help to solve the current issue for you in a sec; because in that case you would keep a strong pointer somewhere outside of the scope and the instance of `SoundController` class won't be released immediately after being instantiated.

Comment: added a member variable for the soundcontroller in the viewcontroller and it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You assign your audioPlayer the wrong way I think this should work.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

class SoundController {
    class func playAudio() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ring-ring", ofType: "aiff", inDirectory: "Media" )!
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            print("Let's play the sound")
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("Error playing sound file")
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SoundController.playAudio()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but i want to keep the SoundController in a seperate class-file. can you alter your code like this?

Comment: well just copy the entire class SoundController to a different file. (row 5-18) :)